# How versioning javascript file on every page request with date

Tags: javascript, html

how i can make version my js file automatically on every page request with realtime date.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <!-- HTML CONTENT -->
     <script src="core.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

on every page request i want to make and force getting new version of js file, like:

```
<script src="core.js?2019-03-19-12-03"></script>
```

is that possible?

Comment: append timestamp

Comment: It depends entirely on the tools you use to generate your HTML (note that forcing a reload of the JS *every time* even if it hasn't changed is likely to be really inefficient and you'd be better off using a checksum (e.g. an md5) of the file instead).

Comment: I didn’t use something for generating my html it’s will be simple html

Answer (score -1):

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime()    
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = 'core.js?' + timestamp
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(tag);
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm not prefer using jquery

Comment: please check this now